# Extract text in <span> class

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following javascript code designed to extract certain text from a webpage.

```
document.getElementById('availability').innerHTML
```

The problem is it extracts the span code as well. This is the output that i get

```
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-success">

        Only 14 left in stock.




</span>
```

However what i actually want to extract is

```
Only 14 left in stock.
```

This is the partial source code of the webpage im trying to extract data off.

```
<div id="availability" class="a-section a-spacing-none">   
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-success">       
        Only 14 left in stock.        
</span></div>
```

I know i can manipulate the extracted data to get the result i want. However i want to know if theres any way via a javascript code i can achieve this? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Sizzle does it like this : https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L918. At first glance you can use the `getText` function as is. You may replace `getText = Sizzle.getText = function( elem ) {` with `function getText(elem) {`.

Comment: If you ever wish to use jQuery than `$('#availibility span').text()` will do the job for you

Comment: jQuery uses Sizzle `getText`, picking the function avoids to load the entire library :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `<span>` is the only child of the empty `<div>`:

```
var el = document.getElementById('availability');
var text = el.innerText || el.textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Jquery in this age.
however you can still use `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById('availability').innerText
```

Comment: Which isn't supported in Firefox. *"You should be using Jquery in this age."* And you should know better than giving such advice.

Comment: Works perfectly. Using Applescript to work with the date, hence the need for javascript. Thanks alot

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for pointing it out.@kype Keeping in mind Felix's comment I would suggest that this is not a complete answer. I can modify, but then I think Alex K. has given better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea here is to use jQuery.

```
$('#availability').text().trim();
```

If you really need to use plain JavaScript, then you need to use for most browsers:

```
document.getElementById('availability').innerText
```

and for Firefox:

```
document.getElementById('availability').textContent
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that the  is the first child of the :

```
document.getElementById('availability').firstChild().innerHTML();
```

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXu25/)

Comment: `.firstChild` and `.innerHTML` are not functions.

Comment: @FelixKling: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/UXu25/, works at least in firefox, not sure about other browsers.

Comment: @Ankit I've checked and it doesn't work on your fiddle. Like FelixKling said, they are attributes not methods, see spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-169727388

Comment: I don't know which Firefox version you are using, but in Firefox 26, I get the error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).firstChild is not a function`.

Comment: @Ankit I've slightly modified your fiddle in order to help you to see the error : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/ctLFn/.